# Windows Git client for private repositories?

Tags: windows, git

I have always used TurtoiseSVN but this time I want to checkout code from a private Git repository at the company, so its address is like `http://github.Company.com/Project/AddAbc.java`.

I found the github for windows program but I think it is only for working for the official GitHub website?

So how can I check out my code? Are there other clients available?
Unfortunately I am on Windows .

Comment: Btw. please don't confuse Git with GitHub. The former is the technology (thus git repository etc.), the latter a mere web service that happens to offer a very nice UI and free online repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're used to Tortoise, there is also TortoiseGit, which works in a similar way but for Git repositories:

https://tortoisegit.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should definetly check out the [msysgit - Git for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) project that offers a reasonable shell that comes with Git installed. In case you haven't yet, you really want to get used to the Git CLI tools - trust me.

For the checkout, do:

```
# cd projects/addabc
# git init
# git remote add origin http://github.Company.com/Project/AddAbc.git
# git remote -v
# git pull origin master
```

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention the superb [Git - Book](http://git-scm.com/book) that's available online.

Comment: thanks, I did this but it didn't check out it..it just created the hooks, etc...but where is the file it checked out?

Comment: @BDotA The `git remote add origin REMOTE_URL` command needs to be given the correct URL to your company's Git repository. Please contact your administrator or maintainer to ask for the correct URL.